# for loop is not working correctly after first loop

Tags: java, swing, for-loop

I wish to create a simple TicTacToe GUI Game by using Swing;
I created JFrame called `TicTacToe` and put JPanel in it called `gamePanel` with `GridLayout(3,3)`. Then I created a button array called `buttons[][]` for my buttons, in which I'll put icon of `X` or `O`. Then I generated 9 buttons and 
added logic. JPanel code:

```
public class gamePanel extends JPanel {
XOButton buttons[][] = new XOButton[3][3];
boolean isX;
public gamePanel() {
    setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 3));
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            buttons[i][j] = new XOButton();
            buttons[i][j].setIcon(null);
            add(buttons[i][j]);
        }
    }
    isX = true;
}

private class XOButton extends JButton {
    ImageIcon X, O;

    public XOButton() {
        X = new ImageIcon(gamePanel.this.getClass().getResource("X.png"));
        O = new ImageIcon(gamePanel.this.getClass().getResource("O.png"));
        addActionListener(this::actionPerformed);
    }

    public int getValue(XOButton btn){
        if(btn.getIcon().toString().equals(null)){
            return 0;
        }
        if(btn.getIcon().toString().equals(X.toString())){
            return 1;
        }
        if(btn.getIcon().toString().equals(O.toString())){
            return 2;
        }
        return 0;
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if(getIcon() != null) return;
            if (isX) {
                setIcon(X);
                isX = false;
                checkWinner();
            } else {
                setIcon(O);
                isX = true;
                checkWinner();
            }
    }

    public void checkWinner(){
            for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
            if(getValue(buttons[i][0]) != 0 && getValue(buttons[i][0]) == getValue(buttons[i][1])
                && getValue(buttons[i][1]) == (getValue(buttons[i][2]))) {
                if (getValue(buttons[i][0]) == 1) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, X);
                    return;
                } else if (getValue(buttons[i][0]) == 2) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, O);
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

I was wondering if I can get an answer for the problem (please!):
As you see, i created procedure called `checkWinner`and yet it is only checking if button icons are equal in one row. But when I use this code, it works properly only for first row. The second and third are ignoring until I will fill the first two buttons of first row. When code works, it should show message with an image of X or O (depends on who is winner).
[Image where it works fine in the first row](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yVuNE.png) and
[Image where it is not working (until I will fill first row for a half)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vT1Oy.png)
When I'll fill first row in second image it will display both two `messageDialogs` with `X` and `O` image.

What am I doing wrong?
I'll also appreciate answers and comments about my code, it's terrible and I want to improve my skills.
Thanks for paying attention.

Edit: I get this exception when pressing any of the button:

```
`Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at gamePanel$XOButton.getValue(gamePanel.java:34)
at gamePanel$XOButton.checkWinner(gamePanel.java:61)
at gamePanel$XOButton.actionPerformed(gamePanel.java:51)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1967)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2308)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:405)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:262)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:270)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6589)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3342)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6354)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2260)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4966)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2318)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4798)
at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4906)
at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4535)
at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4476)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2304)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2772)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4798)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:772)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.access$600(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:715)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:97)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:745)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:743)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:742)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
```

`

Comment: You should either run a debugger or have checkWinner dump out it's parameters when it starts.  At a glance I don't see anything that should prevent it from working, but I didn't make sure your board is being filled in correctly.

Comment: I forgot to tell that I get these errrors when pressing any buttons.

Comment: there are 8 cases for win condition. don't itterate just check each case. HORIZ:[0][0],[1][0],[2][0]  [0][1],[1][1],[2][1]  [0][2],[1][2],[2][2]  VERT:  [0][0],[0][1],[0][2]  [1][0],[1][1],[1][2]  [2][0],[2][1],[2][2]  DIAG:  [0][0],[1][1],[2][2]  [2][2],[1][1],[0][0]. check if all elements are equal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In getValue:

```
btn.getIcon().toString().equals(null)
```

btn.getIcon() is null for an unclicked Button. 
The toString() therefore raises a NPE.

Try to change this to

```
if(btn.getIcon() != null)
```

the same for the other if's

```
if(btn.getIcon() != null && btn.getIcon().equals(X))
```

instead of

```
 if(btn.getIcon().toString().equals(X.toString()))
```

Comment: Thanks alot for your answer! Looks like it should work. But I should use toString() because without it I cant compare button icons. btn.getIcon().equals(X) is not working.

Comment: I added toString() and it works perfectly! Thanks, frank!

Answer (score 0):

In `getValue(XOButton btn)` this line

```
if(btn.getIcon().toString().equals(null))
```

throws a NullPointerException if the icon has not yet been set.

The icon is only set if you click on a button.

Replace your first condition in `getValue(XOButton btn)`  with

```
    if(btn.getIcon() == null){
        return 0;
    }
```

If the icon has been set (the other two cases) won't be a NullPointerException.

Comment: Exactly! Thanks, Thomas! I had read that original question before I asked this, but I handled exceptions badly.